# Filepond auto trigger revert action for local files on form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file, filepond

I'm using Filepond in my project and its successfully working in upload and save case.

But in a scenario, where I've to retrieve all elements including uploaded files on separate page.

So, in that scenario, I send an json:

```
'source' => 1,
        'options' => [
            'type' => 'local',
            'file' => [
                'name' => 'abc',
                'size' => 100,
                'type' => 'image/...',
            ],
            'metadata' => [
                'poster' => 'file_path',
            ],
        ],
```

to ajax response and uploaded files are shown in filepond element, but while submitting the form (pre-populated files) Filepond automatically trigger the `revert` method and `delete` the uploaded files.

Regards

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've a similar case. I add already existing images via the load request, setting type to `local`. I then add a new file and after the process method was successful, the revert method is triggered and i don't know why and how to prevent that.